# Some of my atlas animations have cropped and only showing half

Tags: xcode, animation, atlas

All my animations were working fine, I was adding a boss fight in level 12

Got it working but the player ship that I wasn’t working on was only showing the back half, as if it had been cropped! Yet still animated as normal.

When I tried a clean build I tested level 1 and the player ship is still cropped, along with some other animated nodes, like the weapon power up symbols.

All the other animations are working ok.

Any ideas what could cause this?

Answer (score 0):

I finally worked out what was wrong and how to fix it. I had made lots of atlas files but a Xcode update didn’t like the way I had made them or the location I put them. I deleted all the atlas files and made them inside the Assets.xcassets file, using the menu and selecting create atlas sprite file.

Now all my animations work as they should